# im getting this error while im tring this.in flutter. previos versions i build it this way but i now cant. flutter snapshot mapping

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

im getting this error when i doing now. but i did it previously not get any error. i need to do this for print this details to my flutter app. so i cant find the answer..

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:hit_app/pages/HomePageViwe/Product.dart';

class DatabaseServise{
  final String uid;

  DatabaseServise({this.uid});
  
  //collection reference 
  final CollectionReference productsReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("products"); 

  //product list from snapshot
  List<Product> _productListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
    return snapshot.docs.map((e){
      return Product(
        name: e.data()["name"] ?? "",
        img : e.data()["Image"] ?? "",
        country: e.data()["Country"] ?? "",
        discription: e.data()["Description"] ?? "",
        mulImg: e.data()["multiimage"] ?? ""
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  //get product stream
  Stream<List<Product>> get products{
    return productsReference.snapshots().map(_productListFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X3E2.png)

this is the pubspec files

```
 cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^3.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0
  firebase_database: ^7.1.2
  crypto: ^3.0.1
  lottie: ^1.1.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  flutter_signin_button: ^2.0.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  image_picker: ^0.8.3+1
  image_cropper: ^1.4.1
  scoped_model: ^1.1.0
  firebase_storage: ^10.0.1
  geoflutterfire: ^3.0.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.7
  animate_do: ^2.0.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  line_icons: ^2.0.1
  drop_cap_text: ^1.1.3
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.1.0
  provider: ^5.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to wait for async operations to finish.

Second they changed the way you get data.. if you look you can see if your .data() is a type of Object or a Map<String, dynamic>.. if it is an object you cannot acces data like if it was an iterable...

So you have to cast it like this

```
var myData = e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
```